# Looking for HP Pavilion dv6000 laptop webcam driver for Vista 64bit?

Tags: drivers, webcam, hp-pavilion

It's not listed on HP's website (well half of drivers listed on the page for this laptop didn't work anyways). Can anyone provide a driver that will work? Also, the mic is not working either -- my guess is that the mic is built-in with the webcam, so witout webcam driver, the mic is not working either.

Much appreciated.

Edit: and yes, I removed the recovery partition by accident which has made my life much harder.

Comment: Order recovery discs...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00810334&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

Comment: If HP no longer has them, buy them here...http://www.computersurgeons.com/Default.aspx

Comment: Post the full product number and I can point you to the drivers page at HP, dv6XXXxx

Comment: The laptop (on screen) says it's HP pavilion dv6000, but on the bottom  under product it say HP pavilion dv6500. It's a special edition multimedia entertainment laptop.

Also, under device driver, under imaging options, the HP webcam shows up. But it's not working (via gchat, that is). The mic is not work as well. There is one "unknown device" under device manager. Suggestions?

Comment: Pick yours from this list, then you will find your drivers....http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/pfinder?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&tool=&query=dv6500#N29

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you installed the correct chipset driver?  If you haven't installed the correct chipset driver, or haven't installed one at all, that could be the problem.  You'll need the exact model number of the laptop.  The easiest way is to go [here](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/support-drivers.html) and click Detect Your Product.  More detailed instructions [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c00033108).  Then go to the link Moab provided and download the appropriate chipset driver for the laptop:

   h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/pfinder?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&tool=&query=dv6500#N29
2. If that doesn't work, is the system under warranty?  If so, you can ask their technical support:

   h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/contacthp
3. If it isn't under warranty, you could try on HP's forums.  Someone there might be able to help:

   h30434.www3.hp.com/psg/
4. As a last resort: I can't vouch for the reliability or efficacy of any of the driver sites, but many of them provide software to scan the system for drivers:

   - scan.driverguide.com/scan.php
   - driverzone.com

These links may also prove to be useful:

h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01114052&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en#N957
h10010.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=it&dlc=it&cc=it&docname=c01237075